# Is it possible to rerender/update an each block in Svelte when a variable changes?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

So, I'm pretty new to svelte and very new to sveltekit, but ever since I started learning svelte I've always seemed to run into this problem one way or another.

Here, I have an each block:

```
{#each {length: wordLength} as _, i}

<button class={getGuessInfo(i).state}
        on:click={() => changeColor(index)}>{getGuessInfo(i).letter}
</button>

{/each}
```

And I want to basically have this be reactive to my getGuessInfo()'s return value. I get you can make a function reactive if it doesn't have any parameters, but I'm not sure how to / if it's even possible to if the function relies on an index value.

Here is the `getGuessInfo()` definition:

```
function getGuessInfo(index) {

  if (index > $Guess.length - 1) return {letter: "", state: LetterState.MISS}

  return $Guess[index]

}
```

This basically just returns a blank letter/state if the index is too high, and the letter/state of Guess at that position if not.

This works fine when I open the website, but changing the value of Guess yields no reactivity from the page.

Honestly, I'm so new to frameworks/web development in general that I'm not really sure what I want as a solution, but maybe something like just rerendering the component? Or just the each block? Not sure.

Thanks!

Well, I tried doing:
`$: $Guess && getGuessInfo()`
But that obviously didn't work

I previously just had an each block that was *directly* tied to Guess, as in:
`{#each $Guess as btn, index}`
And that worked fine

Thing is I want to constantly have 5 (or wordLength) buttons showing at all times, even if they're blank. That's why I tried using the function

Comment: *I want to basically have this be reactive to my getGuessInfo()'s return value* - As far as I understand this should update when $Guess changes? Adding it as a parameter `getGuessInfo(i, $Guess)` would have this effect

Comment: @Corrl thank you so much man! I don't know if I can or how to mark this as answered... but thank you this solves it!!

Comment: Great! I just added it as an answer. Voting via the arrows or marking as solved via the checkmark on the left of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the result of a function call reactive, add the variable based on which it should update as parameter - in your case

```
getGuessInfo(i, $Guess)
```

(Would be cleaner to not only add it in the function call, but also in the function definition. But if the variable is in scope, that's not essential)

Answer (score 2):

The reactive attempt is not too far off, you probably could define the function reactively like this:

```js
$: getGuessInfo = index =>
    index > $Guess.length - 1 ?
      { letter: "", state: LetterState.MISS } :
      $Guess[index];
```

This should cause it to be re-evalutated when `$Guess` changes.

(Ternary operator just for brevity, you could use a block & `return` statements.)